# I see some warnings in mysql part of apache docker installation

Tags: mysql, docker

I installed php:8.0.9-apache under docker and checking logs after installation I see some
warnings in mysql part :

```
2021-10-15 14:48:59+03:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.35-1debian10 started.
2021-10-15 14:49:00+03:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2021-10-15 14:49:00+03:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.35-1debian10 started.
2021-10-15T11:49:00.429892Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2021-10-15T11:49:00.432747Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.35) starting as process 1 ...
2021-10-15T11:49:00.437047Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2021-10-15T11:49:00.437068Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2021-10-15T11:49:00.437072Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-10-15T11:49:00.437077Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2021-10-15T11:49:00.437081Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-10-15T11:49:00.437085Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2021-10-15T11:49:00.437330Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-10-15T11:49:00.437445Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2021-10-15T11:49:00.439834Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2021-10-15T11:49:00.451513Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-10-15T11:49:00.454482Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2021-10-15T11:49:00.473993Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2021-10-15T11:49:00.511954Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-10-15T11:49:00.513212Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-10-15T11:49:00.679673Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-10-15T11:49:00.681160Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2021-10-15T11:49:00.681185Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2021-10-15T11:49:00.681582Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-10-15T11:49:00.732209Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.35 started; log sequence number 12659641
2021-10-15T11:49:00.734197Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2021-10-15T11:49:00.737074Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2021-10-15T11:49:00.744353Z 0 [Warning] World-writable config file './auto.cnf' is ignored.
2021-10-15T11:49:00.746941Z 0 [Warning] World-writable config file './auto.cnf' has been removed.

2021-10-15T11:49:00.747343Z 0 [Note] Salting uuid generator variables, current_pid: 1, server_start_time: 1634298540, bytes_sent: 0,
2021-10-15T11:49:00.747433Z 0 [Note] Generated uuid: 'e3496a7a-2dad-11ec-9925-0242ac160002', server_start_time: 281476611009197, bytes_sent: 94189482984608
2021-10-15T11:49:00.747464Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: e3496a7a-2dad-11ec-9925-0242ac160002.
2021-10-15T11:49:00.777304Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2021-10-15T11:49:00.777328Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2021-10-15T11:49:00.777334Z 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
2021-10-15T11:49:00.777336Z 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
2021-10-15T11:49:00.781639Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-10-15T11:49:00.781737Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2021-10-15T11:49:00.782643Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2021-10-15T11:49:00.782677Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2021-10-15T11:49:00.782690Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2021-10-15T11:49:00.782702Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-10-15T11:49:00.793751Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2021-10-15T11:49:00.800000Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 211015 14:49:00
2021-10-15T11:49:00.853789Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2021-10-15T11:49:00.854072Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.35'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

In docker-compose.yml I have :

```
mysql_db:
    container_name: Hostels4J_db
    image: mysql:5.7.35

    restart: always
    environment:
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=dbname
        - MYSQL_USER=user
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=321
        - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=false
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=321
```

Testing how app works these warnings seems not critical, but I am not sure have I try to fix them
or I can I get rid of them? I would like to see my logs as clear as possible...

**MODIFIED # 1 :**
But where have I to change the file permissions ?

In the docker-compose.ymlfile I have :

```
mysql_db:
    container_name: Hostels4J_db
    image: mysql:5.7.35
    # image: mysql:8.0.21
    restart: always
    environment:
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=DockerHostels4J
        - MYSQL_USER=docker_user
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=4321
        - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=false
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=321

    volumes:
        - ${DB_PATH_HOST}:/var/lib/mysql
```

and in Dockerfile.yml :

```
RUN  docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql zip gmp bcmath pcntl ldap sysvmsg exif  \
&& a2enmod rewrite
```

These are all mysql options I have...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the warnings you could solve, but in general they should have a impact pn your system.

Comment: Pls, any hints how to fix them

Answer (score 1):

Inside the mysql container image there seems to be a file auto.cnf that is world writable. Maybe the file permissions are set to 777? Reduce these permissions before running the container.

This is usually done at build-time using `docker build ...` and some `Dockerfile`.

MODIFIED 1:
In your dockerfile you will like to have something like

```
RUN chmod <less access privileges> <full path to auto.cnf>
```

To verify when running `docker build`, you could use

```
RUN ls -l <full path to auto.cnf>
```

Since your log output above only gives a relative path I cannot tell where exactly to find that file. But you could again use

```
RUN find / -name auto.cnf
```

There is one exception actually: if you happen to find the file inside the container in `/var/lib/mysql`, then actually it got mapped in there as external filesystem. In that case find the file in the hosts filesystem location, reduce the permissions and do not worry about the Dockerfile any more.

Comment: Please look MODIFIED # 1